# Thread-Safe Singleton Synchronized() in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, singleton, synchronized

In our app, we use singletons in several locations, and recently I went through and added `@synchronized` commands to all of the singleton methods to ensure that they are thread-safe. My question is what the difference is between calling this:

```
+ (RLReceiver *) getReceiver
{
    static RLReceiver *receiverCache;
    @synchronized(receiverCache)
    {
        if (!receiverCache )
            receiverCache = [[RLReceiver alloc] init];
        return receiverCache;
    }
}
```

In this case I synchronize the static instance of the class `RLReceiver`, but I have also seen (and the compiler surprisingly allows) this as well:

```
+ (RLReceiver *) getReceiver
{
    static RLReceiver *receiverCache;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!receiverCache )
            receiverCache = [[RLReceiver alloc] init];
        return receiverCache;
    }
}
```

Where the synchronize is on `self`. This confuses me a little, since this method is a class method, and there shouldn't even be a `self` inside this scope of this method. Can anyone shed some light on what the difference is between the static variable and self  is in this context, and how there would even be a self inside of a class method?

Comment: The first one is synchronizing on nothing the first time through.  The second one synchronizes on the class object of the object.  (Not 100% sure it's legitimate to do so.)

Comment: It's probably wiser to use one of the schemes employing `dispatch_once`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple Doc: "The object passed to the @synchronized directive is a unique identifier used to distinguish the protected block. If you execute the preceding method in two different threads, passing a different object for the anObj parameter on each thread, each would take its lock and continue processing without being blocked by the other. If you pass the same object in both cases, however, one of the threads would acquire the lock first and the other would block until the first thread completed the critical section."

// Apple example:

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)anObj
{
@synchronized(anObj)
{
    // Everything between the braces is protected by the @synchronized directive.
}
}
```

In your case, how Hot Licks says the problem is the first launch. Your object doesn`t exist in the first launch and the synchronized doesn't work properly. If you try:

[1]

```
 +(RLReceiver *) getReceiver
{
static RLReceiver *receiverCache;

@synchronized(receiverCache)
{
    if (!receiverCache ) {
        receiverCache = [[RLReceiver alloc] init];

    }
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Numbers in order i %i",i);
    }

    return receiverCache;
}
}
```

and [2]

```
+ (RLReceiver *) getReceiver
{
static RLReceiver *receiverCache;

@synchronized(self)
{
    if (!receiverCache ) {
        receiverCache = [[RLReceiver alloc] init];

    }
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Numbers in order i %i",i);
    }

    return receiverCache;
}
}
```

From another object calling in the first time something like that:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("OtherQueue", 0), ^{
RLReceiver *rece= [RLReceiver getReceiver];
});
RLReceiver *receSorF = [RLReceiver getReceiver];
```

You could see how in the [1]case the numbers are mixed and synchronized is not working. In the [2] case one count wait the other.

We can use the object when we synchronize code in a existed object, in other case class name.

Thanks @HotLicks.

Comment: Good answer. I think that my confusion came from the fact that inside a class method `self == [RLReceiver class]` It was just strange to me that self inside a class method refers to the class object, and in an instance method self refers to the instance of the class. It seems like you shouldn't be able to use self at all inside a class method.

Comment: Uh, what is being synchronized on the first time that the first version is called?  `receiverCache` will be `nil`.

Comment: @HotLicks you are right. The first time will be null. But It´s null until fire: receiverCache = [[RLReceiver alloc] init]; and It will be synchronize by null. It´s much better use self.

Comment: Given that the only time you actually need the synchronization is the first time through, I'd say that that's not a trivial matter.  "Much better" is an understatement.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks, in this case self it`s the only option as you said.